# How get ID selected record in UICollectionView

Tags: ios, swift, collectionview

I have this code:

```
@IBOutlet weak var collectionView1: UICollectionView!
    @IBOutlet weak var collectionView2: UICollectionView!

    @IBAction func TipDetailBtnPressed(_ sender: Any) {
       showSubViewInContainerView(view: "TipDetailsView", parm: 0)
    }
    @IBAction func TipDetailPDFBtnPressed(_ sender: Any) {
        showSubViewInContainerView(view: "TipDetailsPDFView", parm: 0)
    }

    let tipObjectArray = [
        TipObject(id: 1, description: "Jakość frytek nas nie zadawala", image: UIImage(named: "a1.jpg")),
        TipObject(id: 2, description: "Kolor frytek jest niesatysfakcjonujący", image: UIImage(named: "a2.jpg")),
        TipObject(id: 3, description: "LOT i reklamacja", image: UIImage(named: "a3.jpg")),
        TipObject(id: 4, description: "Olej nie spełnia naszych oczekiwań", image: UIImage(named: "a4.jpg")),
        TipObject(id: 5, description: "jakiś fajny", image: UIImage(named: "a5.jpg"))
    ]

    let leafletsObjectArray = [
        LeafletsObject(id: 1, description: "AV-AddedValueFries-Ulotka", image: UIImage(named: "d1.jpg")),
        LeafletsObject(id: 2, description: "AV-AddedValueFries-Ulotka 23112", image: UIImage(named: "d2.jpg")),
        LeafletsObject(id: 3, description: "Ulotka", image: UIImage(named: "d3.jpg")),
        LeafletsObject(id: 4, description: "Fajna ulotka", image: UIImage(named: "d4.jpg")),
    ]


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        collectionView1.dataSource = self
        collectionView1.delegate = self
        collectionView2.dataSource = self
        collectionView2.delegate = self
    }

    func showSubViewInContainerView(view: String, parm: Int){
        let viewController = self.parent as! MainViewControler
        viewController.showSubViewInContainerView(view: view, parms: parm)
    }
}

// MARK: - UI
extension TipViewController: UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource{
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        if collectionView == collectionView1 {
            return tipObjectArray.count
        }
        else {
            return leafletsObjectArray.count
        }
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        if collectionView == collectionView1 {
            let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Cell1", for: indexPath) as! TipCollectionViewCellTips
            cell.titleLabel.text = tipObjectArray[indexPath.item].description
            cell.imgView.image = tipObjectArray[indexPath.item].image
            return cell
        }
        else {
            let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Cell2", for: indexPath) as! TipCollectionViewCellLeaflets
            cell.titleLabel2.text = leafletsObjectArray[indexPath.item].description
            cell.imgView2.image = leafletsObjectArray[indexPath.item].image
            return cell
        }
    }


func showSubViewInContainerView(view: String, parms: Int){
        let controller = storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: view)

        systemContainerView.subviews.forEach { $0.removeFromSuperview() }

        if view == "ConceptGalleryView" {
            let con =  controller as! ConceptGalleryViewController
            con.idGallery = parms
        }


        systemContainerView.addSubview(controller.view)
        addChildViewController(controller)
        controller.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        systemContainerView.addSubview(controller.view)

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            controller.view.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: systemContainerView.leadingAnchor),
            controller.view.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: systemContainerView.trailingAnchor),
            controller.view.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: systemContainerView.topAnchor),
            controller.view.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: systemContainerView.bottomAnchor)
            ])

        controller.didMove(toParentViewController: self)

        self.actualVisibleView = view
    }

}
```

The showSubViewInContainerView function displays the views in containerView.

My storyboard: https://i.stack.imgur.com/a39qB.png

In TipDetailBtnPressed and TipDetailPDFBtnPressed I have function:

```
showSubViewInContainerView(view: "TipDetailsView", parm: 0)
```

In parm - I need to insert the ID of the clicked record (item) from collectionView item. How can I do this?

Comment: you can use the delegate func collectionView (collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath),
then retrieve the array data according to the selected collectionCell indexPath

Answer (score 0):

With help of didselect we can able to find what data selected and tow variables to save in class level

```
var lastTipId: Int!
var lastLeafId: Int!



func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        if collectionView == collectionView1 {
            lastTipId = tipObjectArray[indexPath.item].id
            print(lastTipId)
        }
        else {
            lastLeafId = leafletsObjectArray[indexPath.item].id
            print(lastLeafId)
        }
    }
```

Comment: it does not work correctly. Your code returns the number of all items - not the one I click

Comment: I have updated the code please let me know i will share the complete code which works fine for me

Comment: https://pastebin.com/Kd7vVJiH - this is my code now. It's doesn't work. If I'm clicking on the button - I have this result: @@@@@@ nil i nil
Error message. I have account in bitbucket. If you send me email to trifek [*..@..*] iCloud.com - I send to you invitation to my project

Comment: You have to make selection in collection view to get value in lastTipId & lastLeafId . I think you have clicked on button directly

Comment: send an mail for invitation

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172408/discussion-between-vinodh-and-triff).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172468/discussion-between-vinodh-and-triff).

Answer (score 0):

```
var lastTipId: Int?
var lastLeafId: Int?
```

//

```
 func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, 
         didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    if collectionView == collectionView1 {
       lastTipId = tipObjectArray[indexPath.row].id
    }
    else {
       lastLeafId = leafletsObjectArray[indexPath.row].id
    }
 }
```

//
Before you set the var to the function parameter

```
if selectedTipId == nil {

   // Alert the user to select a tip

   return
}
showSubViewInContainerView(view: "TipDetailsView", parm: selectedTipId!)
```

Same in the other button click

Comment: you have to first select a cell or give the vars default values

Comment: you always print selectedleafletId make sure tp use the var that corresspond to the btn wether it tip or leaf

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I changed the code to:
https://pastebin.com/zMd3KWFv

and I get for: showSubViewInContainerView (view: "TipDetailsPDFView", parm: selectedleafletId!) - error: Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Comment: one moment please

Comment: Now I have this: https://pastebin.com/xzcHhL9k and problem with: showSubViewInContainerView(view: "TipDetailsView", parm: selectedTipId!) - Cannot convert value of type 'TipObject' to expected argument type 'Int', selectedTipId = tipObjectArray[indexPath.row].id - Cannot assign value of type 'Int?' to type 'TipObject?'

Comment: From this code: https://pastebin.com/FjBGz6fr I have always resoult: @@@@@@ nil i nil
Error message

Comment: select a cell then click the button by default both vars are nil until you click the cell and it's value change to the id of the clicked item